# Link add cart in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I know in Magento 1 you can add product to cart by id via:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl("checkout/cart/add/product/4671/")?>
```

How do I do the same thing in Magento 2?

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Answer (score 1):

//you can use like this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
// get product object if you are not having
$product = $productHelper->load($id);
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');

echo $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
```